# Comment line in sudoers file linux

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I would like to comment the line of `Defaults requiretty` in `sudoers` file

I need to do it in shell script as part of automation install

I wrote the following ;

```
sudo sed -i 's/Defaults requiretty/# Defaults requiretty/g' /etc/sudoers.old
```

(`sudoers.old` is a copy of sudoers - to try it first on another file)

However, it didn't comment the line.

How do I do comment the Defaults requiretty line via shell?

Comment: Not very good idea to edit sudoers manually. You'd better use `visudo` for this.

Comment: thanks, but I need shell

Comment: And I have a snapshot of the machine BEFORE I do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your sed command like below.

```
sudo sed -i '/Defaults requiretty/s/^/#/' /etc/sudoers.old
```

If there are more than one spaces exists between the words `Defaults` and `requiretty` then it's better to use the below.

```
sudo sed -i '/Defaults \+requiretty/s/^/#/' /etc/sudoers.old
```

or

```
sudo sed -i '/Defaults[[:space:]]\+requiretty/s/^/#/' /etc/sudoers.old
```

Comment: it didn't replace it :(

Comment: thanks. you are right. there was 5 spaces between Defaults to requiretty. how can I control it if I am not sure about the spaces?

Comment: `sudo sed -i '/Defaults \+requiretty/s/^/#/' /etc/sudoers.old` or `sudo sed -i '/Defaults \{5\}requiretty/s/^/#/' /etc/sudoers.old`